# Checkbox with custom image on-check does not working in JSP using spring framework

Tags: html, jsp

I used to show a custom image on check in the check box, but it is not showing when I integrate the code inside JSP.

Comment: Are you using class background image?

Comment: Yes, I am adding and removing class using jQuery.

Comment: You please inspect the code check is there any input[type=hidden] elements present?

Comment: yes, there are fields with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following code in you JS or in JSP with in  tag. It will solve the issue.

```
var addonCheckboxes = $("input[type=hidden][value=on]")
for (var i = 0; i < addonCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    addonCheckboxes[i].remove();
}
```

Thank you.